# how to configure Light Table to always show Workspace

Tags: settings, lighttable

I'm trying to configure Light Table to show Workspace and load the last workspace on startup.

Is it possible? What Tag to use?

```
[:app :lt.objs.app/???]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[:app :lt.objs.sidebar.workspace/workspace.open-on-start]
```